# getting parent object and passing to other methods via a form in between

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Thanks for the upvote and appreciation done.

http://jsfiddle.net/AUcu6/1   the black arrow.  i when the create task is hit.  it opens a form,   form submit button makes an ajax call.       Now , i need form values in that ajax call (thats simple to get the values by #form id and field) , but HOW to get the parent of  the clicked arow div and pass THAT to the ajax call method

I might get the FIRST parent of a div that has .someClass by `$(this).parents(".someClass").first()`   but how to actually do it practically and move the value to or through the form and then to the ajaxcall method.

**the form is actually in between the clicked div and the ajaxmethod call**

Comment: Your fiddle link doesn't work

Comment: @jlars62 fiddle might be down momentarily. I have replaced it with new one

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. What exactly are you trying to pass to the ajax method? and why?

Comment: @jlars62 "why" is a long story, "what" is = form values (easy) + parent of the clicked div. and I need to pass it on submit button click

Comment: Ill listen to the long story, I'm just trying to figure what you are actually trying to do because I think there is an easier solution than the way you are approaching it.

Comment: I need to send some params to the ajax call, that goes to server.those params and reasons would take the whole page to explain. its just that I want the id of its paren (the first parent that has a certain class) + form values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is one way to do this.

Take a look at this code:

```
<form id="createForm">
   <input name="task-title"></input>
          ^^^^  

   <textarea name="task-description"></textarea>
             ^^^^ need the name for all inputs you care about

   <input id="parentVal" type="hidden" name="parentVal"/>
   <input type="button" value="Create" class="create..." onClick="ajaxCreateTask();" />
</form>

<script> 
   function ajaxCreateTask(){
      $("#parentValue").val("getValueYouWant"); //sets the hidden input which makes it part of the form
      $.post("url", $("#createForm").serialize());
   }
 </script>
```

Now let met explain a little how this works. When the `serialize` method is called, it basically turns the form into a map. The `keys` of the map are the `name` attributes and the values are the values of the inputs. We use a hidden input to contain the extra data - the parent data of the button clicked or whatever you want it to be. Then, you simply called the post jquery method which makes a post request to the url which is the first parameter, and the request contains the data in the second parameter, which is your form data. [This](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page is really helpful.

Let me know if that helps and if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks, one way to acces the  object's parent which was clicked is by putting it in a global variable at the time of click. window.parent. then it can be access in any m!ethod. Thanks for the tip